# NGINX configuration unexpected end of file

Tags: nginx, syntax

It's really confusing, it continually asks me for to put a } at the end of a file every time I try restart NGINX, this is the configuration I'm working with:
http://pastebin.com/s2CcbmG5

running the NGINX config test gives me

```
Aug 24 16:21:44 rain nginx[5028]:  * Starting Nginx Server...
Aug 24 16:21:44 rain nginx[5028]: nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:198
Aug 24 16:21:44 rain nginx[5028]:    ...done.
```

So I put a } or a ; thinking that might work and of course, it just asks me for another } below the one I just inserted. I'm having trouble understanding this sytax. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

at line 152 your SSL ciphers is not completed and no } for http directive

Comment: It is complete, it ends with a ;   I think it was improperly formatted when I uploaded it through the pastebinit CLI.

Comment: At line 152 it end with 

ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH$

both preview text and RAW paste data. But at line 83 it ok.

Comment: I just fixed the issue, same error, removed both lines from both blocks and the error persists, it still wants me to put a } at the bottom, doing so results in the same error.

Comment: oh, one more issue is no } close for http {

Comment: If I close the http block it responds with 

nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:60

the http block was never altered from the original config, all my additions to the config are below the ######default######## bar as far as I know.

Comment: from pretty format http://pastebin.com/S14EcjMy you will see that no } for http directive.

Comment: Just try to 
nginx -t